# Probability that sum of random variables is positive

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, order-statistics

We have $n$ standard Gaussian random variables $x_i \sim N(0,1)$ and constants $a_i \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$. We select the $k$ smallest $x_i$ in magnitude in a set $K$ and define $Z:= \sum_{i \in K} a_ix_i$.

What is the probability that $Z\geq 0$: $Pr(Z \geq 0)$.

I was wondering if this is even computable. Since we multiply the $x_i$ with a constant we obtain $a_ix_i \sim N(0, a_i^2)$. But now we cannot simply derive the probability distribution of the sum of $a_ix_i$, since we do not choose them randomly but select the smallest $x_i$ in magnitude.

Hence, I was thinking about order statistics. But for order statistics we need that the random variables are iid, which they are not since they have a different variance.

Am I correct? Or does there exist a way.

I would even be happy with something like $Pr(Z\geq 0) \geq ...$, but unfortunately since we do not know anything about $a_i$ I don't see how something can be derived.

Comment: Just the total hyperarea of $\binom{n}k$ disjoint regions of intersecting hemispheres in $S^{n-1}$ which should be easy enough to compute for fixed $n,k$.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your comment. Unfortunately I don't understand what exactly you mean. May you please explain a bit more?

Comment: Isn't it the case that mapping the outcome $\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ to the outcome $\{-x_1,\dots,-x_n\}$ is probability preserving, and thus the answer is exactly $\frac12$ by symmetry? (unless all of the $a_i$ equal $0$)

Comment: I was wondering the same. But since we take not all variables into the set $K$ I think the answer is not correct.